# Intellij IDEA jpa console issue select from tables with specific columns

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, intellij-idea, eclipselink

We have a project includes Eclipselink and MySQL.

For example if we use simple query:

```
SELECT a from ExampleTable a
```

it is transformed to something like this:

```
SELECT `id`, `code`, `high`, `key`, `name`, `regionalCode` FROM `ExampleTable`
```

and if I am using JPA Console I am getting something like that:

```
SELECT id, code, high, key, name, regionalCode FROM ExampleTable
```

and error message

```
[42000][1064] You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'key, name, regionalCode FROM ExampleTable' at line 1
```

The problem is "key" column but I have no chance to rename it.

I tried to find options to fix that but have no results.

I think if there will be no answer - the good way is to create bug report.

**How we get enclosed names of columns?**

We are using [EntityManager](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html)

```
EntityManager em;
...
TypedQuery = em.createQuery("SELECT et FROM ExampleTable et");
```

And if we run it we see (in debug mode) that all names in generated query are enclosed with ` symbol.

Answer (score 2):

`key` is reserved keyword of MySQL database (see [MySQL: Reserved Words](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/reserved-words.html)).
so you should escape reserved keyword in your mapping.
You can do it in the following way:

```
@Table
@Entity
public class ExampleTable implement Serializable
{
   // ...
   @Column(name = "'key'") // or @Column(name = "\"key\"")
   private String key;
   //...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but if we do that Eclipselink transformes it to: SELECT \`'key'\` FROM ExampleTable; and fall with MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column ''key''.

Comment: @LemonTree How did you create table with such column (key)?

Comment: It is legacy. And system is too heavy and complex to change column name.

Comment: @LemonTree I don't understand, why generated sql query looks like `SELECT 'id', 'code', 'high'...` when should be `SELECT id, code, high...`

Comment: This is the question. And is there any options to disable this behavior in Eclipselink.

Comment: @LemonTree Please, show `CREATE TABLE ...` query, that creates this table